# Crystal Reports: Weekly standard deviation with multiple entries per week

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, standard-deviation

What I am trying to do is get a weekly standard deviation of Qty
I managed to get a sum of each week; however when I do this I can not get a standard deviation from these values. It tells me that these value cannot be summarized

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bskgT.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb12p.jpg

If anyone has any ideas I would be very appreciative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the StdDev function can only take a field as an argument. You are using the summary. You could try:

```
stdev({Mathlist.Qty}, {Mathlist.Date}, "weekly")
```

as

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftopic533.html

EDITED:

1) To get the sum of the week averages, create a formula like below. Put it in the group footer (by date, weekly).

```
shared numbervar counterOfWeeks;
shared numbervar sumOfWeekAverages;
sumOfWeekAverages := sumOfWeekAverages + Sum ({Result.Valor}, {Result.Data}, "weekly");
counterOfWeeks := counterOfWeeks + 1;
sumOfWeekAverages; //this will print the result, you can suppress it, you know
```

2) To get the average of the week averages, create a formula like below and put it in the report footer.

```
shared numbervar sumOfWeekAverages;
shared numbervar counterOfWeeks;
numbervar missingWeeks := 0;
if counterOfWeeks + missingWeeks > 0 
then sumOfWeekAverages / (counterOfWeeks + missingWeeks)
else 0;
```

Note the "missingWeeks". You can use it as an artifice to treat the weeks with no value, i think you can calculate it.

It's not the full solution, but i believe it is a step toward it, according to your comment. Let me know if you did not get the the desired result.

EDITED AGAIN:

Now, calculating the stddev without the sum.

1) Create a formula like below. Put it in the group footer (by date, weekly).

```
shared numbervar counterOfWeeks;
shared numbervar sumOfWeekAverages;
shared numbervar sumOfSquares;
sumOfWeekAverages:= sumOfWeekAverages+ Sum ({Result.Valor}, {Result.Data}, "weekly");
sumOfSquares:= sumOfSquares+ (Sum ({Result.Valor}, {Result.Data}, "weekly"))^2;
counterOfWeeks:= counterOfWeeks+ 1;
```

2) Create a formula like below and put it in the report footer.

```
shared numbervar counterOfWeeks;
shared numbervar sumOfSquares;
shared numbervar sumOfWeekAverages;
numbervar missingWeeks := 9;
numbervar n := counterOfWeeks + missingWeeks;
if n > 1 then
    sqr((sumOfSquares - (1/n) * (sumOfWeekAverages^2)) / (n - 1))
else 
    0
```

But you still need to find a way to determine the "missing weeks". I set it to 9 for a test and got exactly the result you posted (835,40). I can send you the RPT file if you want.

Comment: Yes I believe that is the problem. Your solution does give me a standard deviation; however it is not the correct standard deviation. I'll try to clarify a little bit.


http://imgur.com/a/TPTXG


The information comes in like the top picture. By using a sum I managed to group it by week, but like you said I can't do a standard deviation of it anymore. To make matters worse, there are weeks with 0 quantity, and this needs to be taken into account get the proper standard deviation. The last picture represents that in an excel spreadsheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't figure out a way to use the information that I summed. If I could call these sums somehow, I could write the formula for standard deviation manually. @heringer

Comment: Though you cannot pass the sum as parameter for the stddev function, you can call it in the formula. It is ok if you write "sum({Mathlist.Qty}, {Mathlist.Date}, "weekly)" in a formula. But i am not sure if it is enough to calculate it "manually".

Comment: Yea, when I try to use that as a formula, it just uses the last number in the group as opposed to using all of the values.

Comment: I simulated it here and i've got the final sum using a shared variable. I will edit the answer and put it on it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Ne5kVWNThe column boxed in red is the unsummed weekly values
The unboxed column is the summed weekly values
the column boxed in red is the weekly sums using you first formula
What it is doing is adding together the previous the column boxed in red and the unboxed column. It also doesn't reset itself when it gets to a new group. Your other formula to get the average didn't work because it didn't take into account the zero values. I figured out a way to do this using a total sum and dividing it by the number of weeks. I used the datediff function to find the number of weeks

Comment: Yes that would be helpful I think. In order to determine the missing weeks, what I did was count the number of weeks, as well as a record count. Numberofweeks-RecordCount would equal the number of missing weeks.

Comment: It works great on the first group; however it doesn't reset itself before going on to the second group.

Comment: I thought that it was the desired result. Maybe i did not understand it very well. Anyway, you can create another formula that reset the shared variables wherever you want. Maybe put it on the group footer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain my last response very well. http://imgur.com/vvOTtvf For part #300 it works perfectly, but part #103A and all parts after use date from previous parts so their standard deviation values are incorrect.

Comment: Everything is working great now, thank you for your help @heringer